# knows which link the user pressed before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the next code:

```
<td colspan="2" style="padding:5px 0 10px 5px;">
    <a class="Option" id="option1" onclick="func1();">1</a>
    <a class="Option" id="option2" onclick="func2();">2</a>
    <a class="Option" id="option3" onclick="func3();">3</a>
</td>
```

it seems something like:

[image]

when the users pass between 1,2,3, the Body is changed to the fit body (by a javascript function).

I want that each function (`func1`, `func2` and `func3`) will know if the user came from one of the functions: `func1/func2/func3`, or not. (maybe alert: "yes" or "not").

p.s. the user can arrive to these functions from another pages..

**for example**,

**In the image I attached, if the user presses 2, I want that in func2, I will know that he was in `1` before he came to 2.**

Any help appreciated!

Comment: have a variable `prev` that could keep track of what the previous tab was... and whenever you change a tab just change `prev` after you've done what you wanted with it.

Comment: The stuff about users coming from functions and arriving in functions from other pages makes no sense.

Comment: take one global variable to save previous visit function state in one .js file and include in all files so that when u'll update this variable after calling any function can be accessible in other pages also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            a{border:1px solid red;cursor:pointer;}
        </style>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>   
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a class="Option" id="option1">1</a>
                    <a class="Option" id="option2">2</a>
                    <a class="Option" id="option3">3</a>
                </td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
        <div id="result">teste</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 

            var previous = 'None';
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.Option').click(function(e) {
                    $('#result').html(previous);
                    previous = $(this).prop("id");
                    e.preventdefault;
                });
            });
            //]]>  

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcugt/)

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I found this method to get the function name

```
<a class="Option" id="option1" onclick="func1(1);">1</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function func1() {
    var functionName = arguments.callee.toString().match(/function ([^\(]+)/)[1]
    alert(functionName);
}
</script>
```

alerts "func1".

But this is not reliable. As far as I know, there is no standard way to get the name of a function.

Answer (score 1):

as pandavenger and deepi said, I saved a global variable: "came_from", and in the end of each functions (func1,func2 and func3), I init it by: 1,2,3..

```
var came_from = 0;

func1() {
   if (came_from != 2 && came_from != 3) { do something }
   .....
   came_from = 1;
}

func2() {
   .....
   came_from = 2;
}

func3() {
   .....
   came_from = 3;
}
```

thank you all!